# How to tell ReDJ to redirect all except given paths (negate /path1 and /path2)?

Tags: redirect

I am struggeling with ReDJ to configure redirection.

I want to redirect all URLs except given once.

e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/something
https://www.example.com/something/abc
https://www.example.com/something/abc?id=0815
https://www.example.com/somethingOther
https://www.example.com/somethingOther/cba
https://www.example.com/somethingOther/cba?id=0816
```

to a subdomain lets say

```
https://mysub.example.com/...
```

But I do **not** want to redirect

```
https://www.example.com/path1
https://www.example.com/path2
https://www.example.com/otherPath
```

Hope someone can help?

Comment: Do you mean? `/https:\/\/www.example\.com\/(?!otherPath|path[12]).*/`? I don't  have ReDJ, so I don't know what you are after.

Comment: sadly this regex did not work.
I need to do some cleanups for SEO with category links

Comment: You can trial your regex patterns on regex101.com if you know all of the _actual_ strings.  It's nearly impossible to provide a quality regex pattern based on hypothetical urls.

Comment: my assumption with regex was:
www.example.com(/path1|path2|/otherPath) and to add negates to the paths in the braces, but I did not find a valid negate variant.